# USB Driver won't install properly

Tags: android, usb, driver

I'm trying to get my phone to connect with Eclipse so I can run android apps without using an emulator. I've already gotten this to work and made an app, but I got a new hard drive since then. Every time I try to reinstall it on the new hard drive, it says that it doesn't install properly. I've tried using 2 different usb cords, rebooting every time I try it and installing/uninstalling the USB driver from the Motorola website to no avail, and I can't remember exactly how I did it before.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your usb debugging turned on and use this free software to install the driver :

http://adbdriver.com/

Answer (score 1):

Android's development page doesn't explain this one in full detail. I had problems with it myself. Although my situation wasn't exactly like yours, installing the usb driver from the SDK made it work.

Follow this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/)!